# spherical radial basisfunction

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

As a spherical radial basisfunction we defined it by:

There is a function  $F$ on

$\mathscr{F} := \partial K_1 (o) $

with with the characteristic that there exist a function $G$ with

$ G:= [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ 
and a point $y \in \mathscr{F} $

so that: $ F(x) = G(xy) $ for all $ x \in \mathscr{F} $

I want to show, that there exist a function 
$ H:[0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , so that
$F(x)= H (|x-y|) $

and if F is continous, then:

$ \int_{ \mathscr{F}} F(x) do(x)= 2\pi \int_{-1}^1 G(t) dt $

I tried to get an idea behind those radial basis functions, but could not develop ideas to solve this one.
therefore any help is very appreciated! :-)
__
Edit:

I got a hint:
1. look for the case where $ y=(0,0,1) ^T $

2. then represent it for any $ y \in \mathscr{F} $ by a rotation $(0,0,1)^T= Ay $, where $ A^T=A^{-1} $

sadly, I still can not get this task solved

Comment: or can someone explain what radial basis functions are for? :)